# BizTalk Mapping EDI N2 field (in an outbound message)

Tags: biztalk, edi, biztalk-2013

What's the best practice for mapping decimals in EDI schemas? 
The assembler seems to be flexible to allow them to be there or not. 
I had one case on a QA system, where same map, but two customers were getting different results.  I was thinking it had to be a party configuration option. 
This is for outbound X12 EDI 210 (version 401)

Schema

Note on sample below: L102 is define as R, and L104-L106 are defined as N2.

```
L1*1*111.00*FR*11100****LHS~  (Correct) 
L1*1*111.00*FR*111.00****LHS~ (Incorrect)
```

I was hoping the Party settings: 
 under Local Host Settings, checking the box for "Convert implied decimal format NN to base 10 numeric value" would fix, but later I read this is only for incoming EDI messages.

I did a test where I mocked up a 210 XML, just showing a fragment below with the results to the right side of L104-L106. This seems to show that if no decimal there, the two decimal places are implied, but if decimal is there, that overrides.

```
Sample1
        <ns0:L1>
            <L101>1</L101>
            <L102>111.00</L102>    
            <L103>FR</L103>   
            <L104>111.00</L104>    EDI Value 11100 
            <L105>111</L105>       EDI Value 111
            <L106>11100</L106>     EDI Value 11100 
            <L108>LHS</L108>
        </ns0:L1>

Sample 2
        <ns0:L1>
            <L101>1</L101>
            <L102>111.00</L102>    
            <L103>FR</L103>   
            <L104>111</L104>        EDI Value 111
            <L105>111.0</L105>      EDI Value 11100
            <L106>111.00</L106>     EDI Value 11100 
            <L108>LHS</L108>
        </ns0:L1>
```

So two questions: 
1) Is there a party setting to fix my issue where one customer is right and one is wrong? 
2) What is the best practice for mapping decimal places in the BizTalk supplied XML/EDI schemas?

Comment: I'd be interested in the answer to this too. Did you read the microsoft docs?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/configuring-edi-properties